# Storing a JObject as a property of a C# class in Mongo DB

Tags: c#, mongodb, json.net

I have a C# class I'm storing in Mongo DB as a document, using the default mongo C# driver.  I've added to this class a property, which is as follows:

```
public JObject Payload {get;set;}
```

Where `JObject` is a type from the Newtonsoft JSON library.  When it is serialized to Mongo, I get documents that have the correct set of keys and structures, but all of the values are the names of types in the Newtonsoft library.  For example:

> "Payload" : {
>           "fieldOne" : "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject, Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed",
>           "fieldTwo" : {
>               "Person" : {
>                   "attributeOne" : "JObject",

and so on.  How can I get this document to save correctly, such that instead of the type names in the values, I have the actual values?  Is my only recourse to write a custom serializer for the Newtonsoft types?

Answer (score 2):

We changed the type from `JObject` to `BsonDocument`, and when we set the property, we use `BsonDocument.Parse` on the string representation of the object.  We use the `.ToString()` method on the property when we need to re-extract the JSON Value.  This seems to work.

Comment: Yes, but remember that this will not work if your object is an array.